# Want a recursive function which numbers its args, recursing into lists

Tags: r, recursion

Suppose I have a list,

```
l<-list(a="",b="",c=list(d="",e=list(f=""),g=""))
```

and it looks like:

```
List of 3
 $ a: chr ""
 $ b: chr ""
 $ c:List of 3
  ..$ d: chr ""
  ..$ e:List of 1
  .. ..$ f: chr ""
  ..$ g: chr ""
```

Now I want to assign values based on the order of the lists, to the last character vectors. For example, the value for `l$a` would be "1", the value for `l$c$d` would be "3.1", and the value for "l$c$e$f" would be "3.2.1".
I created a recursive function to generate and assign the values:

```
sequencize<-function(list,loopn="1"){
  if(!is.list(list)){
    list<-loopn
  }else{
    for(i in 1:length(list)){
      sublist<-list[[i]]
      newloopn<-paste(loopn,i,sep=".")
      sequencize(sublist,newloopn)
    }
  }
  list
}
```

However, when I run `sequencize(l)`, it returns an identical list as the input, with no values assigned to the vectors.
So can anyone please tell me what the problem is with my function?

Comment: The `for()` loop doesn't return anything. All those calls to `sequencize` are being thrown away essentially. What do you want to do with them. Also, you are not changing the value of `list` in the `else` block and `list` is the value your function is returning.

Comment: For the love of God, `list()` is a builtin in R... so don't shadow it by naming a variable after it!

Comment: Sorry, @smci, I don't follow you. What do you mean by "don't shadow it by naming a variable after it"? Can you explain in detail?  I am not a native English speaker:).

Comment: If you type `list` when you start R, you see it's a `function (...)  .Primitive("list")`. Don't hide that definition within your function, by redefining it as one of your function args: `function(list,...) ... list<-loopn ...`. Don't call the function arg `list`, call it e.g. `arglist` or `ll` or something that isn't a builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you actually construct and return a new list in your recursive function:

```
sequencize <- function(list, loopn="1") {
  if (!is.list(list)){
    loopn
  } else {
    l <- lapply(1:length(list), function(i) sequencize(list[[i]], paste(loopn,i,sep=".")))
    names(l) <- names(list)
    l
  }
}
str(sequencize(l))
# List of 3
#  $ a: chr "1.1"
#  $ b: chr "1.2"
#  $ c:List of 3
#   ..$ d: chr "1.3.1"
#   ..$ e:List of 1
#   .. ..$ f: chr "1.3.2.1"
#   ..$ g: chr "1.3.3"
```

Comment: Thank you, and @MrFlick, for your prompt replies! I've taken your answers and thought for a while; however, I'm still not quite sure what was wrong. In my view, although the for loop itself does not return anything, but the "if" block returns the value, and when the function recurses to the end, it will definitely hit the "if" block, right?  Am I wrong about the logic or does it have something to do with some mechanisms in R?   I am relatively new to R and have no experience in any other programming languages, so any further information will be appreciated!

Comment: @NickZeng in the `else` part of your if statement you make the recursive call but never store the results anywhere. Therefore when you return `list` at the end it returns the original list.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the replies and struggling for a day, I finally understood what the problem was, and found a solution:

```
sequencize<-function(lst,loopn="1"){
        if(!is.list(lst)){
                lst<-loopn
        }else{
                for(i in 1:length(lst)){
                        lst[[i]]<-sequencize(lst[[i]],paste(loopn,i,sep="."))
                }
                lst
        }
}

> str(sequencize(l))
List of 3
 $ a: chr "1.1"
 $ b: chr "1.2"
 $ c:List of 3
  ..$ d: chr "1.3.1"
  ..$ e:List of 1
  .. ..$ f: chr "1.3.2.1"
  ..$ g: chr "1.3.3"
```